# How to enable v-model on custom component?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to wrap a TexField ui to a new custom component so that I can add extra functionalities and reuse the component within the project. I want it to still have the v-model binding so I implemented the following:

```
:text="text"
```

and

```
@textChange="(update)=>{$emit('textChange', update.value)}"
```

Wherein "text" is its prop named and exposed exactly as a normal TextField prop.

The pattern should work on web but I don't know if it's possible on nativescript vue component. Please have a look at the code I made in playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Ikap1R&v=1

It's not working. Please help if you know the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing you have to do specifically for {N}, if you know how it works with Vue.js, you got it.

All you have to do is, use a `value` prop for input value and emit `input` event on change.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Ikap1R&v=2)